# Parsing missing column values CSV in Spark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge DB imported table with ~270 columns, I created a JavaRDD and used it to fill a dataframe.

Scenario: if all the fields in the CSV file are present then everything is great. But if there some empty field in CSV eg.

```
Value1,,,,,,value7,,,,,
```

then on writing to parquet of hive table store fails due to Indexoutofbound exception (column>row size). I don't want to use the `spark-csv` library.

I tried using filters but of no use as I need all column even if there is no data in the CSV. Please let me know if I am missing on something.

```
JavaRDD<String> tLogRDD =jsc.textFile(dataFile);    
        String schema=tLogRDD.first();

            List<StructField> columns =new ArrayList<StructField>();
            for(String fieldName: schema.split(","))
            {               
            columns.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName,DataTypes.StringType,false));
            }                   
        StructType schemaStructType = DataTypes.createStructType(columns);
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXX-Row Read Start-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = tLogRDD.map(
                  new Function<String, Row>() {
                      @Override
                    public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
                      String[] fields = record.split(",");
                      Object[] fields_converted = fields;
                      return RowFactory.create(fields_converted);                 
                    }
                  });
        //apply schema to rows  
        DataFrame tLogfDataFrame=hContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schemaStructType);
        System.out.println("DataFrame Constructed Successfully");
        tLogfDataFrame.show(10);
        tLogfDataFrame.save("C:/Users/Documents/1001.csv","parquet");
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the spark-csv library?

Comment: The ubuntu machine is fenced inside proxy,sbt fails to download dependencies jars for spark-csv(required to build along with shell), if I add manually (--jars on spark submit)then it throws main not found exception error. I am trying to understand how the library finds all the rows on CSV even if some column may not have any value. I am finding it difficult to map all the columns. My best guess is to do something during datafile JavaRDD planning(Line 1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv reader from spark,,
like:

```
sparkSession.read()
.format("csv")
.option("header","true")
.option("inferSchema","true")
.load(--file path--)
```

That's easier and has set of options.